# Options for Skype / Dialer when calling from app

Tags: android, skype, phone-call, lync

I am creating an application from which the user can call people. In this application I would like to give the option of using either the phone's dialer or other VOIP applications such as Skype or Lync (which incidentally are both Microsoft software). My only problem is that they don't seem to be registered to listen for android.intent.action.CALL (this gives me the phone), but only for android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED - via which I cannot reach the phone's dialer (I'm guessing that's the privileged part). I'm developing on a stock Nexus 4 btw.

Is there a pretty way that I can launch my intent and be given the option of both the dialer and also Skype/Lync?

Right now my calling the intent looks like this:

```
Uri numberUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
intent.setData(numberUri);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Feel free exchange the contents of the intent for Intent.ACTION_CALL - I'm doing it all the time at the moment.

Comment: Mark, did you every find a way to launch a Lync (or Skype) call from an intent?

Comment: No, no solution. I think someone needs to go hit first Google then Microsoft with a big stick to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Dear this cannot be possible.